# Sign Up link from upvoting on random SE Site does not suggest existing Network Profile

Tags: discussion, bug, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I just attempted to vote on a question I found via a google search:

> [The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)

The site looked very similar to Stack Overflow, the programming Q&A site I use all day and on which I upvote often, so I was confused when my upvote was not recorded.

I consult my Address Bar, and realize I'm on a *different* Stack Exchange site. Because I have never been to this random site before, I cannot upvote the question. I find that decision questionable. But, I digress.

I'm willing to create yet another new Stack Exchange account ("YANSEA") in order to record my vote. After attempting to upvote, I receive a nice pop-up to do just that:

[image: Sign up or log in]

> Thanks for the feedback!
>
> This action requires 15 reputation.
>
> Setting up an account is free and open to everyone. Set up your account today and earn extra privileges like posting, commenting and voting.
>
> Sign up or log in
>   - Sign up using Google
>   - Sign up using Facebook
>   - Sign up using Email and Password

I have a 15k rep Stack Overflow account logged in and open in another tab. I'm also logged in on Stack Exchange, and can view my accounts and Network Profile.

But none of the buttons allow me to automatically create a new account under my existing Network Profile!

When I select the **Google option**, I'm taken to a page listing every multiple google account that is currently logged in to google/gmail. I do not know which one, if any, is associated with my Stack Exchange account, and desperately want to avoid creating a *new* Stack Exchange account that is not linked to my current Stack Overflow account. I abandon the Google sign-in.

When I select the option with a **Stack Exchange logo**, I am taken to [a page to "Create your account" for the specific site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypH4C.png). When I then click "Log In", I'm taken to [a Stack Exchange login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agiaj.png) with no reference to my currently logged-in Stack Exchange account.

Why is this system not automatically finding my logged-in Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange account and creating the new network site account automatically?

I did not end up voting for the question because I was unable to create an account on the site.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Do you login with Google or have a separate SE login? I see this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dROgf.png), which upon clicking the "Join this Community" button prompts me to log in with my google account.

Comment: @EthanK under "My Logins" I have one Stack Exchange (email/password) and 2 google logins associated with my account. If it matters, the site was [StackApps](https://stackapps.com). Checking now, for the [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) site, I see the same "Join" link as you instead...

Comment: I think StackApps is special with its login process because of the site's functionality, but I see the same "Join this Community" on StackApps as well. I still can't reproduce.